# Exclude in webpack-obfuscator does not work

Tags: javascript, webpack

We have implemented the obfuscator as per https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator.
We have only three subfolders in our project under the root: node_modules, src, dist. We expect these to all be non-obfuscated with the appropriate exclude in plugin, so the subsequent code in the bundle is not obfuscated at all. (This is, of course, just an intermediate step to make sure the exclude works at all. In the end, we just want to exclude node_modules from obfuscation).

The versions javascript-obfuscator (4.0.0) and webpack-obfuscator (3.5.1) are both the latest and should therefore be compatible?!

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "metrolyzer_npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "includes information about all modules required for the Metrolyzer",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.jetbrains.space/else42/metro/metrolyzer.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "bootstrap": "5.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "d3": "^7.7.0",
    "dat.gui": "0.7.7",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "three": "0.123.0",
    "three-orbit-controls": "^82.1.0",
    "three.meshline": "^1.4.0",
    "troika-three-text": "0.45.1",
    "xlsx": "0.10.8"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-obfuscator": "^3.5.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
var WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map" // Allows us to get more detailed information about the source of an error
  },
  devtool: "source-map", // Allows us to get more detailed information about the source of an error
  optimization: {
    minimize: false, // Minimization should enabled for production 
  },
  plugins: [
      new WebpackObfuscator({rotateStringArray: true}, ['*node_modules*','*src*','*dist*'])
    ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sass|css)$/,
        use: [ // The use of a loader is required because we are using .css from bootstrap
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        enforce: 'post',
        use: {
          loader: WebpackObfuscator.loader,
          options: {
            rotateStringArray: true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: We were able to reproduce and resolve the problem. Two things had to be changed in order to make the exclusion of folders/files work.

1. Removing the line: `new WebpackObfuscator({rotateStringArray: true}, ['*node_modules*','*src*','*dist*'])` from the variable `plugins`. We suspect this to be redundant.
2. Use `path.join()` instead of `path.resolve()` when specifying which folders/files should be excluded. `path.resolve()` was resulting in `C:\node_modules` rather than `C:\Users\ ... \ ... \ ... \node_modules\`

After implementing these changes our issue was resolved. Below is the resulting webpack.config.js. Changes to the config other than the ones described in 1. and 2. can be ignored.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
  },
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "buffer": require.resolve("buffer")
      }
    },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  optimization: {
    //minimize: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
        exclude: [
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/src/example/gui.js'),
        ],
        enforce: 'post',
        use: {
          loader: WebpackObfuscator.loader,
          options: {
            reservedStrings: [ '\s*' ],
            rotateStringArray: true,
            identifierNamesGenerator: 'mangled-shuffled',
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /\.(sass|css)$/,
        use: [ 
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```